# Android: Connect sunshine to the cloud

Tags: android

i am beginner in android, i am currently learning android studio through udacity course online, which is create a sunshine apps. Now, i am in trouble in lesson 2 which is connect sunshine to the cloud, i follow all the step but still reach a problem: Unfortunately， sunshine has stopped. I try to use DDMS tool to debug, but i still can't solve it.

below are the message in the log cat:

```
01-18 16:12:50.667 16173-16173/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-18 16:12:50.697 16173-16184/? V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 138 SET_CORE_SETTINGS: 0 / Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=60]
01-18 16:12:50.697 16173-16184/? V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 110 BIND_APPLICATION: 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{40e687a8 com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app}}
01-18 16:12:50.707 16173-16185/? V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 100 LAUNCH_ACTIVITY: 0 / ActivityRecord{40e6ae18 token=android.os.BinderProxy@40e6a558 {com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivity}}
01-18 16:12:50.717 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: >>> handling: SET_CORE_SETTINGS
01-18 16:12:50.717 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: <<< done: SET_CORE_SETTINGS
01-18 16:12:50.717 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: >>> handling: BIND_APPLICATION
01-18 16:12:50.727 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: <<< done: BIND_APPLICATION
01-18 16:12:50.727 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: >>> handling: LAUNCH_ACTIVITY
01-18 16:12:50.737 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/SystemTheme/Resources: createSystemThemeIfNeeded
01-18 16:12:50.737 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/SystemThemeResource: SystemThemeResource: set to default lenovo theme
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17963: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17967: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-18 16:12:50.747 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-18 16:12:50.777 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-18 16:12:50.777 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-18 16:12:50.777 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-18 16:12:50.787 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-18 16:12:50.787 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-18 16:12:50.787 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18480: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18480: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-18 16:12:50.797 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ba6ac8)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5138)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5109)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5138) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4714)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5109) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5138) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment" on path: /data/app/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app-1.apk
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4714) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5109) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5138) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-18 16:12:50.807 16173-16173/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-18 16:12:50.907 16173-16184/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 102 PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING: 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@40e6a558
01-18 16:12:51.577 16173-16185/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 140 TRIM_MEMORY: 20 / null
01-18 16:12:51.577 16173-16185/com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app V/ActivityThread: SCHEDULE 109 DESTROY_ACTIVITY: 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@40e6a558
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: There are some inflate exception in your code. First solve it then proceed

Comment: Its show Class Not Found Exception, Please make sure com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment and is it really exist or not..

Comment: so i have to solve both ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a comment, due to less reputation i can't add a comment so posting it as a answer.

From the logcat pasted above at a glance it shows `"com.cheeleong1993.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"` class is not found so ensure that  MainActivity class has below code snippet 
`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new MainActivityFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }`

And activity_main.xml has below code snippet

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Then it should resolve your error. if you still face the error then do share your xml and class files where you are inflating the fragment in the mainactivity class.

Hope this helps
Cheers.